# DotNetNuke module position and panes

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have been using DotNetNuke for a couple of weeks but there is one thing I can't figure out.  How can I find out which pane a module currently resides in.  I have used mostly version 7 but I have tried version 6 too.  I can't find this information anywhere.

When a page is in Edit Mode in 7.x there is an option to move a module to a different pane by hovering over the Move Icon.  DNN displays a list of panes where the module can be moved when the mouse is over the Move Icon.  DNN knows what pane the module is currently in because the current pane is excluded from the list.  However, under the Settings for a module there is no property to tell you in which pane the module resides.

This is really important because most skins have LOTS (20+) of different panes.  Usually panes are collapsible it is quite hard to tell which pane a module is in based solely on the position of the module on the page.  Knowing the current pane of one module is required to get the correct layout when you add new modules.

The only thing that works is to use process of elimination.  I can figure out a module's current pane if I can find which pane is NOT in the list of panes where I can move that module.  This method is tedious and un-usable if you are trying to work with modules via the Page Management admin screen.  Am I missing where to find this property or is not available.  If it is not available then is there are better way to position items that I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a layout view? Sorry, I only have DNN 6. I'm assuming DNN 7 still has view / edit / layout view. Layout view was designed for this.

Comment: Layout view only shows module titles.  Most of my modules do not have titles, but I could fix that.  Unlike v6 v7 does not outline the pane when you hover over it in layout view. It is a bit jumbled but an improvement over my current method.  Still do not understand why I cannot find or there does not exist a property on the module showing the pane NAME.

Comment: That probably has more to do with the skin that is being used than the version of DNN. Some skins are more compatible with various DNN features than others. You may be able to indicate at the site-level which container you want your modules to use when they are in edit mode. Other than that, I'm at a loss!

Comment: If you have access to the database through the Admin board, you can query the information you neeed like this: select * from tabmodules where TabModuleID = <id>.
Put your tabmodule id inplace of <id>. The content in the PaneName column is the pane on which your module sits and the TabId column is the ID of the page (see your page raw url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout Mode should show you the PANE names. If you don't have Pane Names then it is possible that the Skin you are using has hidden the the name of the pane, but why they would do that I don't know.

Here's an Example of one of the Panes in my MultiFunction skin (available on codeplex) when in Layout Mode

TopPane